# axios does not sending the header info on get/post request

Tags: javascript, axios

Consider the following code:

```
const restURL = '';

const reqData = {
    'params': {
        'posts_per_page': 50,
        'lang': 'bn',
    }
}

const reqHeaders = {
    'headers': {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-access-token',
        'X-WP-Nonce': 'my-wp-nonce-here',
    }
}

await axios.get(restURL, reqData, reqHeaders)
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

After running this code While I check in the browser developer tools I found that headers data are not in the headers!! Anybody know where I am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`axios.get`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config-1) takes at most two params, `url` and `config`.  You could probably just do:

```
await axios.get(restURL, Object.assign({}, reqData, reqHeaders))
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```